# how to keep first menu expanded in jquery & expand/collapse icon not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown where I have to keep 1st menu expanded & expand/collapse icon. The icon is visible only onclick. By default, the icon is not reflected. I have to insert the icon from my local. Expand/Collapse is working.Maybe my approach to writing code is wrong Please help to fix the icon issue. Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sub-menu ul').hide();
    $(".sub-menu a").click(function () {
        $(this).parent(".sub-menu").children("ul").slideToggle("100");
        $(this).find(".right").toggleClass("expand collapse");
    });
    $('.sub-menu a').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('toggIconUp')){
        $(this).removeClass('toggIconUp').addClass('toggIconDown');        
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('toggIconDown').addClass('toggIconUp');
        //var blockId = $(this).parent().attr('data-toggle-id');
        
    }
});
    
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 170px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #414141;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
.sub-menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #dedede;
    
}
.nav ul li a .icon_sty {
    text-align: center;
    float:right;
}
.nav ul ul {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
.toggIconDown {
    background-image: url(./images/down_arrow.svg) !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    background-position-x: 92% !important;
}
.toggIconUp {
    background-image: url(./images/up_arrow.svg) !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    background-position-x: 92% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class='sub-menu toggIconUp'><a href='#' class="main_menu ">Panel<div class='icon_sty  right'></div></a>
            <ul class="">
                <li><a href='#'>one </a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>two </a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>three </a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>four </a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>five </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
    <li class='sub-menu toggIconUp'><a href='#' class="main_menu ">second<div class='icon_sty  right'></div></a>
            <ul class="">
                <li><a href='#'>second_one </a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>second-two </a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```